# Find the common solution of the PDE $u_{xy}+a(x,y)u_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> > Find the common solution of
> >     $$
> > u_{xy}+a(x,y)u_x=0~~~~~\text{in}~~~~~\Omega:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert x-x_0\rvert<d_1, \lvert y-y_0\rvert <d_2\right\},\\ 
> > d_1,d_2>0, (x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2, a\in C(\Omega)
> > $$

In the meantime, I thought about an answer to this question (see below). Would be great to get a feedback to it.

With kind regards

Answer (score 2):

I add *my* answer in order to get a feedback from you. Please tell me, if my general solution is right or maybe nonsense, would be very kind of you!

---

First of all I use the theorem of Schwarz and substitute $z:=u_x$, getting an ODE of order 1 in $y$ (here $x$ is only a parameter):
$$
z_y=-a(x,y)z~~~~~(1)
$$
If one considers $a$ as only dependent on $y$ and $x$ only as a parameter, then $a$ is continious on the intervall $I:=(y_0-d_2,y_0+d_2)$. So the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* says that
$$
A(x):=\int_{y_0}^{y}a(x,\tau)\ d\tau~~~~~(2)
$$
is an antiderivative on $I$. So I continue (1) by separation of variables, getting
$$
z=C_1(x)\cdot\exp\left(-\int_{y_0}^{y}a(x,\tau)\ d\tau\right).
$$
Resubstituting, it follows
$$
u(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x}C_1(\eta)\exp\left(-\int_{y_0}^y a(\eta,\tau)\, d\tau\right)\, d\eta+C_2(y)~~~~~(3)
$$
with $C_1\in C^1((x_0-d_1,x_0+d_1))$ and $C_2\in C^1(I)$ arbitrary functions.

Comment: Instead of chosing $y_0$ and $x_0$ as lower borders in (2) and (3)it is of course possible to chose any point in $I$ respectively any point in $(x_0-d_1,x_0+d_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

> \begin{align}
> \partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,y}}{x}
> &=
> \exp\pars{-\int_{y_{0}}^{y}{\rm a}\pars{x,y'}\,\dd y'}
> +
> \partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,y_{0}}}{x}
> \\
> \partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,y_{0}}}{x}
> &\equiv
> \left.\partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,y'}}{x}\right\vert_{y' = y_{0}}
> \equiv
> \tilde{\rm u}\pars{x,y_{0}}
> \end{align}

\begin{equation}
{\rm u}\pars{x,y}
=
\int_{x_{0}}^{x}
\exp\pars{-\int_{y_{0}}^{y}{\rm a}\pars{x',y'}\,\dd y'}\,\dd x'
+
\int_{x_{0}}^{x}\tilde{\rm u}\pars{x',y_{0}}\,\dd x'
+
{\rm u}\pars{x_{0},y}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

> In addition,
> $$
> {\rm u}_{x}\pars{x,y}{\rm u}_{xy}\pars{x,y}
> +
> {\rm a}\pars{x,y}{\rm u}_{x}^{2}\pars{x,y}=0\,,
> \quad\imp\quad
> \bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\partiald{}{y} + {\rm a}\pars{x,y}}{\rm u}_{x}^{2}\pars{x,y} = 0
> $$
>
> $$
> \partiald{}{y}\bracks{%
> \exp\pars{2\int_{y_{0}}^{y}{\rm a}\pars{x,y'}\,\dd y'}
> {\rm u}_{x}^{2}\pars{x,y}} = 0
> $$
> and
> $$
> {\rm u}_{x}^{2}\pars{x,y}
> =
> \tilde{\rm u}^{2}\pars{x,y_{0}}\exp\pars{-2\int_{y_{0}}^{y}{\rm a}\pars{x,y'}\,\dd y'}
> $$

Let's assume we have two solutions $\phi\pars{x,y}$ and $\varphi\pars{x,y}$
of the differential equation for given values of ${\rm u}\pars{x_{0},y}$ and
$\tilde{\rm u}\pars{x,y_{0}}$. Then, we have $\delta_{x}^{2}\pars{x,y} = 0$
where $\delta\pars{x,y} \equiv \phi\pars{x,y} - \varphi\pars{x,y}$. We conclude
that
$$
\delta\pars{x,y} = {\rm f}\pars{y}\
\mbox{where}\ {\rm f}\ \mbox{is an }\ {\it arbitrary}\ \mbox{function}.
$$
However,
$$
{\rm f}\pars{y}
=
\phi\pars{x_{0},y} - \varphi\pars{x_{0},y}
=
{\rm u}\pars{x_{0},y} - {\rm u}\pars{x_{0},y} = 0
\quad\imp\quad
\phi\pars{x,y} = \varphi\pars{x,y}
$$

We conclude that the solution $\pars{1}$ is the unique solution for a given boundary conditions as defined by $\ds{{\rm u}\pars{x_{0},y}}$ and
$\ds{\tilde{\rm u}\pars{x_{0},y}
 \equiv
 \left.\partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,y'}}{y'}\right\vert_{y'\ =\ y_{0}}}$.