# Does a continious function on a simple connected domain have an antiderivative?

Tags: integration

> > I consider the domain
> >     $$
> > A:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\lvert x-x_0\rvert < d_1, \lvert y-y_0\rvert < d_2\right\}
> > $$
> >     with $d_1,d_2>0, (x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$
> >     and a function $a\in C(A)$. My question is, if $a$ has an antidervative.

What I know is: $u$ is continious on $A$ and therefore differentiable on $A$. And $A$ is simple connected (because $A$ is a rectangle.)

Does this already imply, that $a$ has an antiderviative?

Comment: What would an "antiderivative" mean in that situation? $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = a$, or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = a$?

Comment: I do not know, i refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528615/find-the-common-solution-of-the-pde-u-xyax-yu-x-0 where I do not know if it's right in general and if the antidervative A exists in particular.

Comment: You have that (such a function exists; $$F(x,y) = \int_{x_0}^x a(\xi,y)\,d\xi$$ does the job). But that's not usually called an "antiderivative".